# Suppose $(f_n)$ is an equcontinuous sequence in $C^0$ and $p \in [a,b]$ is given.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n(p)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, prove that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded.

What I've started is:
$f_n(p)$ is bounded and equicontinous, so by the Arzela-Ascoli Thm, $\exists$ a subsequence $f_m(p) \rightrightarrows g(p)$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta >0$, s.t. $|x-p|<\delta$ and $|f_n(x) - f_n(p)|<\epsilon$.  And

$|f_n(x)-f_n(p)| \leq |f_n(x) - f_m(p)| + |f_n(p)-f_m(p)| < 2\epsilon$

I think that to show that f is uniformly bounded, what I want to show is that:

$sup(|f_n(x) - f_m(p)| \leq M$ for some $M$.

I'm having trouble showing that the $sup$ of things are bounded.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f_n$ is equicontinuous, so for $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $$|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| <\epsilon, \forall n$$
as long as $|x-y| \leq \delta$

For any $x \in [a,b]$, suppose $x >p$, denote $N = \lfloor \frac{x-p}{\delta}\rfloor$, then we have
\begin{align}
|f_n(x) - f_n(p)| =&|\sum_{k=1}^N \left(f_n(x- (k-1)\delta) - f(x-k\delta)\right) + f(x-N\delta) - f_n(p)| \\
\leq & \sum_{k=1}^N |f_n(x- (k-1)\delta) - f(x-k\delta)| + |f(x-N\delta) - f_n(p)|\\
\leq &N\epsilon + \epsilon = (N+1)\epsilon
\end{align}

Since $N = \lfloor \frac{x-p}{\delta}\rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{b-a}{\delta}\rfloor$, we get for $x>p$
$$|f_n(x) - f_n(p) |\leq (\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\delta}\rfloor+1)\epsilon, \forall n$$

Similarly it's true for $x < p$, so we have 
$$|f_n(x) | \leq (\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\delta}\rfloor+1)\epsilon + |f_n(p)|, \forall n$$

So we get $$|f_n(x)| \leq (\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\delta}\rfloor+1)\epsilon + \sup_n |f_n(p)|$$